# Firestore: No setter/field for field for nested class

Tags: java, google-cloud-firestore

I have a class, `MyOptional`, that contains a generic object, in this case `Foo`.
I can see that I am seeing the following warnings in the logs

```
No setter/field for present found on class MyOptional (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
No setter/field for empty found on class MyOptional (fields/setters are case sensitive!)
//The above two are static methods, and the below ones are fields in Foo
No setter/field for f1 found on class MyOptional
No setter/field for f2 found on class MyOptional
...as well as for all other fields
```

The classes look like so:

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyOptional<T> {

  private static final FSOptional<?> EMPTY = new FSOptional<>(null);

  private T value;

  public static <T> FSOptional<T> empty() {
    return (FSOptional<T>) EMPTY;
  }

  public static <T> FSOptional<T> of(T t) {
    return new FSOptional<>(t);
  }

  public boolean isPresent() {
    return value != null;
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return value == null;
  }
}
```

and

```
@Data
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Foo {
  private String f1;
  private String f2;
  ...
}
```

I can see in the db that the data is being saved, however it does show the results/values of my two static methods (`isEmpty()` and `isPresent()` for `MyOptional`).
HOWEVER, I do notice that the base object of the db is Foo instead of MyOptional...

[image: DB result]

I DO have the default constructor and the setters and getters via `@NoArgsConstructor` and `@Data`, for both objects, so I am confused why I am still seeing this warning...any idea why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

I solved the warnings for my methods (isPresent and isEmpty) by adding the following annotation to each method
`com.google.cloud.firestore.annotation.Exclude`.

As for the nested the other warning for the other field, it's not really related to any of this.
Before, I was storing my `Foo` object directly in the database, however I updated it to be a `MyOptional<Foo>` instead. I noticed that when fetching the object the first time I see all the warnings for each field, however, once the object is updated to the new type, I no longer see the warnings.